# A Firefox "master password" feature that's friendly to guest users?

Tags: firefox, security, passwords

I use the "master password" feature of Firefox and like it for a number of reasons. It does have it's drawbacks, though: anytime I hand my laptop over to my girlfriend so she can check her email on it, she's continually confronted with the prompt to enter my master password. I have since disabled the feature and am back to square one.

Is there an addon or tweak that will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make a separate (or guest) account on your machine for her, or make two Firefox profiles in your account.  The first would require her logging in and out over you, assuming Fast User Switching is available; the second would mean each of you selecting which profile to use each time you open Firefox, and closing & reopening Firefox to switch profiles when you hand the machine back and forth.

[Coming back late to add]: An approach I had overlooked for the two-profiles case: Firefox can be told with -P  on its command-line, which profile to use for the session.  Two tiny apps or {shell|Apple}scripts, each with it's own icon on the dock, would make it easy to keep and load his & hers browsers in one user account.

Comment: I'm hoping for a plugin or FF modification that will allow me to switch between using remembered credentials versus not doing so, at runtime. If that doesn't exist, then this official way should be the accepted answer, which is more of a higher level bypass of the issue.

Comment: In this related question
http://superuser.com/questions/90864/how-can-i-make-the-firefox-password-manager-more-intelligent
, the only other suggestions were to use one of several external (to Firefox) password managers.  So I'd guess those are the two directions to explore, other than a DIY solution, such as a script to toggle the value of signon.rememberSignons in prefs.js? But even then, a browser restart would likely be required.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link to the other question, I'd missed that one. Your summary makes sense. And there are a number of potentially viable solutions on the table now. Much appreciated.